# How to set (or remove) timezone for AngularJs UI mix with jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, spring-mvc, jquery-ui, angular-ui-datepicker

I have a input type Date, because my Project user Spring MVC + AngularJs, so ***i used Datepicker of AngularUI, but when value send into Request, timezone always auto minus 7 hours, i looking for all solution but not found anwser***, please help me! This is link guide: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date.
Edit: I from vietnam and GTM+7

```
var app = angular.module('listHistoryApp', ['ui.bootstrap', "ui.select2", 'ui.date']);
app.controller('historyCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $location) {
    $scope.dateOptions = {
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        yearRange: '1970:-0'
    };
};
```

```
<input ui-date="dateOptions" class="span2" type="text" ng-model="fromDate"/>
```

I expect the output when pick `27/6/2019` tobe `2019-06-27` or `2019-06-27T00:00:00.000Z`, but the actual output is `2019-06-26T17:00:00.000Z`.

Comment: I guess it is returning the UTC time. Find a way to get the time in LT.

Comment: Don't use that datepicker. Use the excellent [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) date-picker which is maintained by a larger team.